# Ionic Capacitor - Timer in Background (iOS / Android)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, timer

Is it possible to run a timer in the background (in both iOS and Android) or will it be out of the app-guidelines (specifially on iOS). Right now I am having a meditation-timer-app and one of the most important things is that the time should keep on running while in background mode (if the phone display is black or the home screen is opened).

I am using an interval `setInterval()` - Method of 1000s to count down each second.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/background-task#background-tasks says it may not be possible:

> NOTE: On iOS setTimeout and setInterval won’t work once your app is in background, so don’t use them inside beforeExit.

So another idea that I would have would be to make a calendar event (for example for a Date that is 10 min in the future if you set the timer to 10mins).
Than it would be a scheduled timer event. If you reopen the app, the timer gets adapted to the calendar event.
Is this possible to wait for a specific date to happen? And how?

Do you have a better solution or can I just use the interval in the background somehow?

For my app this would be very important, since when meditating, you don't want to have the phone open. You want to start the timer and put the phone away.

Comment: You could get/save_in_var the timestamp of the moment when your app goes to background, and again when it comes to foreground, and then get the difference between the two and check if its >= to your schedulled time, then run your method

Comment: But when the timer runs out while beeing in the background the ending sound (e.g. gong) should be played in background mode

Comment: did you look into using local notifications - https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications

Comment: did you find a good answer to this?

Comment: tbh I did not work at the project for the past months. Just got into it again and I have other things to solve first in this project.

When I get the time to address this background-timer problem, I would research in calender-scheduled events and custom sound notifications.
So that I set the meditation-timer for - let's say 10 minutes and this will create a calendar-event of a date that is 10min in the future.
After we hit that date in 10min a notification with a custom sound (e.g. singing bowl/gong) will play.

But I won't solve it in the near future since I have other tasks first to do